# RESTful API with MEAN stack

Tags: rest

I've seen several tutorials on building web application with MEAN stack - for example http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 and with all those GET, POST , PUT and DELETE requests to the server are handled in specific way but I always wondered how to make for example when I click a button "Register" to make a POST req and take the data from the inputs to the database or use PUT to update it or DELETE - to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat...

Here's one. On the client side e.g. with JavaScript, read the information inputted to the form by the user. 
e.g.

```
var firstName = myForm.elements["first_name"].value
var lastName = myForm.elements["last_name"].value
```

Then using this information construct an AJAX request and invoke your RESTful web service endpoint.

e.g.

```
POST http://host/my/rest/api/user
```

where the request payload for user might look like:

```
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Smith"
}
```